# Overriding `__str__` for `str` class

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I want to create a subclass of `str` and override `__str__` such that the original methods of `str` (e.g. `upper`, `lower`) use the value returned from the overridden `__str__` method.

```
class MyString(str):
    def __str__(self):
        return "FOO_BAR" + super().__str__()

mystr = MyString(" Hello World")

print(mystr) # FOO_BAR Hello World
print(mystr.upper()) # HELLO WORLD
```

I've tried the above. But it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That sounds like the wrong way to go, on multiple levels. Why not just write a function `def my_string(s): return "FOO_BAR" + s`? Or if you really want a subclass, `__str__` is almost certainly not how you should go about your goal.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica This was a minimal example excluding some details - I want to override some other methods e.g. `__add__` so I can modify the strings in other ways. How should I go about it with a subclass?

Comment: Override `__new__`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ok thanks - so not possible to dynamically generate the string when one of the methods are called? I guess not because strings are immutable?

Comment: Those methods don't use `__str__`. Why would they?